# How to append a session to a url in webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

I am working on the reset password code. When the user clicks on the reset password link sent to him via email,he should be redirected to his account in the application
I have done the following till now.
In the web config I have hardcoded the url in the key value pair:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="RESET_PASSWORD" value="http://localhost:portnumber" />
</appSettings>
```

I have used AppSettings to store the key for RESET_PASSWORD and passed it to a string

```
string resetpassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RESET_PASSWORD"].ToString();
```

and I have passed this string to the `<a href>` tag that I am using for reset password link.

Now I want to pass the session id and do something like this directly in the web config:

```
<add key="RESET_PASSWORD" value="http://localhost:portnumber?uid=<%=Session("userId")%>" />
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?I am getting an error "AppSettings cannot contain text" when I try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`cookieless="true"` setting does this automatically for you.

You need to enable **cookieless** in the **sessionState** part of your web.config.

Please refer [sessionState Element Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx) and [About Cookieless session in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

**EDIT**: Oops! I kind of misunderstood the problem.

Since you are using ASP.NET MVC I would suggest you to map your reset password page (the one that opens from mail) to some controller action. You then need to pass in the User ID and a randomly generated hashkey as GET parameters and save the same hashkey in database. When the user clicks on this link provided in the mail, you need to validate if there is a combination with the User ID and hashkey in the database. If there is one, then the request is a valid one. You can then go ahead with your further steps.

You can use System.Guid.NewGuid() to generate random hashkeys. You should not use session ids for this purpose.